# Преобразование массива int в строку

Tags: c#, cmd

Имеется массив целых чисел, который был получен из строки в кодировке cp866. Как из этого массива получить строку (имеются символы кириллицы)?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `имеются символы кириллицы` Стесняюсь спросить... где?

Comment: В исходной строке

Comment: @Akina, числа - это коды символов исходной строки, если я всё правильно понял. В т.ч. и символы кириллицы.

Comment: Да, и как видно на скриншоте, выходящие за пределы byte.

Comment: а доступ к исходной строке, из которой получен этот массив есть? чтобы получить из нее массив байт

Comment: Увы, нет. Массив получен поочерёдным считыванием целых чисел из этой строки

Comment: А вы могли бы опубликовать строку как текст, а не скриншот?

Comment: И да, _как именно_ был получен массив чисел? В кодировке cp866 нет символов с кодом более 255, так что это явно что-то другое.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду посимвольное чтение? Вообще там явно в наличии символы юникода, и они таки да, совпадают с кирилией. Поэтому я бы попробовал перевести ее так Int16[] => byte[] => string

Comment: Первые символы декодируются в `"Microsoft"`.

Comment: @VladD судя по тегу cmd, получено это выводом какой-то софтины в консоль, при этом сама по себе консоль в windows вполне поддерживает юникод, но иногда почему-то коряво выводит локализованные символы, этим даже системные утилиты грешат, те которые на cpp писаны

Comment: @rdorn: Судя по всему, утилита неюникодная, и/или выводит текст в кодировке CP 866. А консоль настроена в кодировке CP 1251, вот и результат. (То же могло случиться, если какая-то программа берёт вывод консольной утилиты, и показывает его в окне.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш текст:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
>   (c) Корпорация Майкрософт (Microsoft Corporation), 2013. Все п

---

Для начала, нужно превратить картинку в текст, это легко сделать через какой-нибудь онлайн-сервис. Я воспользовался https://www.onlineocr.net/, предварительно откусив в редакторе frame окна (но вообще-то это должны были сделать вы сами!). Получилась следующая строка:

> 77 105 99 114 111 115 111 102 116 32 87 105 110 100 111 119 115 32 91 86 101 114 115 105 111 110 32 54 46 51 46 57 54 48 48 93 13 10 40 99 41 32 1033 174 1072 1031 174 1072 160 1078 1025 1087 32 1034 160 169 1028 1072 174 1073 174 1076 1074 32 40 77 105 99 114 111 115 111 102 116 32 67 111 114 112 111 114 97 116 105 111 110 41 44 32 50 48 49 51 46 32 8218 1073 1168 32 1031

Затем, в строке есть символы с кодами старше 255, но большинство попадают в диапазон ASCII, следовательно, имеет смысл предположить, что это закодированы unicode-значения символов.

Получаем:

```
var s = "77 105 99 114 111 115 111 102 116 32 87 105 ..."; // тут вся строка
var chars = s.Split().Select(int.Parse).Select(n => (char)n);
var intermediateResult = new string(chars.ToArray());
```

Результат выглядит почти хорошо:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
>   (c) Љ®аЇ®а жЁп Њ ©Єа®б®дв (Microsoft Corporation), 2013. ‚бҐ Ї

Латиница на месте, а вот с кириллицей что-то не то. Учитывая наличие упоминания CP 866 в вопросе, предположим, что изначально текст был в кодировке CP 866, и был интерпретирован как текст в какой-то другой кодировке (после чего скопирован в Unicode-формате). Какой может быть другая кодировка? Очевидная версия — кодировка русскоязычных текстов по умолчанию, CP 1251.

В этих предположениях пробуем получить исходные байты, и интерпретировать их назад как символы в кодировке CP 866:

```
var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(intermediateResult);
var result2 = Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetString(bytes);
```

Получаем читаемый результат.

Всё!

Comment: интересно, что означает  "Все п" в конце этой строки? +))))

Comment: @rdorn: «Всем п»?

Comment: @rdorn: А, «все права защищены» :)

Comment: Прям детектив какой-то. Убийца уборщик.

Comment: @RuslanArtamonov: Виновата стрелочница!